# spark.executor.memory not getting set. Showing default value

Tags: apache-spark

I launched my spark program in client mode. Set spark.executor.memory to 24g while creating SparkSession. However when I check in Spark UI logs, I see the spark.executor.memory to be 2g. Why the value is not getting set during SparkSession creation?

Comment: In which mode are you running? YARN or standalone?

Comment: Hi Don, Can you paste the spark-submit command here?

Are you running as standalone, Yarn or Mesos deployments?

Do you have enough resources on your cluster?

Which job are you running stream/batch using checkpoints?

Comment: hi Arnon, Here is my command. spark

Comment: hi Arnon, Here is my command. spark-submit --class <class-name> --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 24g <jar-file-name> <arg1> <arg2>
However later I figured that in client mode even executor-memory must be passed at run time with spark-submit. I am running it with master as YARN. Thanks.

Comment: Some of the configuration parameters in the yarn-site.xml may cause this. You can find some detail about this situation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511019/why-does-not-spark-executor-instances-work/51511340#51511340